# How to catch Argument Error in routes.rb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, routes

In a RAils app, in the routes.rb file, we are routing some legacy URLs like so:

```
get "downloads/item/:slug", :to => redirect {|params| "/downloads/#{params[:slug].gsub('.', '')}"}, :constraints => { :slug => /[^\/]+/ }
```

However, the problem is some of these legacy URLs have non-encodeable characters, like an ellipsis, that breaks the `gsub` command with the error:

**NilClass# (ArgumentError) "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"**

My question is: How do I catch this exception, and thus other exceptions like so in my routes.rb file? I assume this is different than having the "catch-all" at the end of the file to route to a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error happens inside the block, you can use a `begin..rescue`

```
get "downloads/item/:slug", :to => redirect {|params|
  begin
    "/downloads/#{params[:slug].gsub('.', '')}"
  rescue ArgumentError
    "/"
  end
}, :constraints => { :slug => /[^\/]+/ }
```

Read more: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html

Comment: How do I reformat that whole get block above? Yes, it happens in the block with the gsub.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly how I thought it should be done. I really appreciate it.